# Is There Any Way To Call a function is in a function individually outside - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, alert

I don't know my question is right or not. But I need to do if it possible.
Here is my function

```
function parentfunction(){

var child1 = function() {
  alert('abc');
}

var child2 = function() {
  alert('def');
}

child1();
child2();
return false;
}
```

When I Call  `parentfunction()`. I got two alerts. `abc` and `def`.
But Now I need to call `child1()` function individually outside `parentfunction`. But I can't pass any arguments to the functions like `parentfunction(argument)` also No edits to functions.

When I Tried to call `child1` out I got an error in console like.

> VM69:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: child1 is not defined
>       at :1:1

Is there any way to call those function outside.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: No, if you cannot edit the function you cannot access the variables scoped within that function.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use argument to define the function you want to return

```js
function parentfunction(func_num = null){
  var child1 = function() {
    alert('abc');
  }
  var child2 = function() {
    alert('def');
  }
  
  return (func_num !== null)?((func_num == 1)? child1() : child2()): child1()+child2() ;
}
parentfunction(); // main function
parentfunction(1); // for child1
//parentfunction(2); // for child2
```

Comment: Thanks. Its Helpfull. But I Cant Edit main function. Again Thanks for your Answer. Its Also Possible.

Comment: @AdhershMNair Why is _"But I Cant Edit main function."_ not included as description of requirement at original Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry. My Mistake.

Comment: @AdhershMNair Have you considered editing original Question to include the specific parameters of requirement?